# Migrating Domain Controller from Windows 2003 SBS

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2003, domain-controller, migration

I'm trying to migrate DC from Windows Server 2003 SBS to Windows Server 2016. Problems begin when I try to promote Server 2016 to domain controller. I get the following error message on 'Prerequisites Check' step:

`Verification of outbound replication failed. Error reading the NTDS settings on replication source domain controller server.mydomain.local. Domain controller data not found for the specified Active Directory domain controller`

In the forest there where an empty subdomain and a faulty secondary DC (computer it was installed on was lost long ago). I've cleaned these things up with help of `ntdsutil` but it was to no avail. Although `dcdiag` now is almost clean:

```
    Command Line: "dcdiag.exe /v /c /d /e"

Domain Controller Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
   * Verifying that the local machine SERVER, is a DC. 
   * Connecting to directory service on server SERVER.
   SERVER.currentTime = 20201022103523.0Z
   SERVER.highestCommittedUSN = 12822731
   SERVER.isSynchronized = 1
   SERVER.isGlobalCatalogReady = 1
   * Collecting site info.
   * Identifying all servers.
   SERVER.currentTime = 20201022103523.0Z
   SERVER.highestCommittedUSN = 12822731
   SERVER.isSynchronized = 1
   SERVER.isGlobalCatalogReady = 1
   * Identifying all NC cross-refs.
   * Found 1 DC(s). Testing 1 of them.
   Done gathering initial info.


===============================================Printing out pDsInfo

GLOBAL:
    ulNumServers=1
    pszRootDomain=mcad.local
    pszNC=
    pszRootDomainFQDN=DC=mcad,DC=local
    pszConfigNc=CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local
    pszPartitionsDn=CN=Partitions,CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local
    iSiteOptions=0
    dwTombstoneLifeTimeDays=60

    dwForestBehaviorVersion=2

    HomeServer=0, SERVER

    SERVER: pServer[0].pszName=SERVER
        pServer[0].pszGuidDNSName=12a36ed6-9156-4bb8-9d8a-f523bd78ff47._msdcs.mcad.local
        pServer[0].pszDNSName=SERVER.mcad.local
        pServer[0].pszDn=CN=NTDS Settings,CN=SERVER,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local
        pServer[0].pszComputerAccountDn=CN=SERVER,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=mcad,DC=local
        pServer[0].uuidObjectGuid=12a36ed6-9156-4bb8-9d8a-f523bd78ff47
        pServer[0].uuidInvocationId=46209efa-f56d-4587-b190-36daf538829a
        pServer[0].iSite=0 (Default-First-Site-Name)
        pServer[0].iOptions=1
        pServer[0].ftLocalAcquireTime=0c27e930 01d6a85f 

        pServer[0].ftRemoteConnectTime=0bf56780 01d6a85f 

        pServer[0].ppszMasterNCs:
            ppszMasterNCs[0]=DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=mcad,DC=local
            ppszMasterNCs[1]=DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=mcad,DC=local
            ppszMasterNCs[2]=CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local
            ppszMasterNCs[3]=CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local
            ppszMasterNCs[4]=DC=mcad,DC=local

    SITES:  pSites[0].pszName=Default-First-Site-Name
        pSites[0].pszSiteSettings=CN=NTDS Site Settings,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local
        pSites[0].pszISTG=CN=NTDS Settings,CN=SERVER,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local
        pSites[0].iSiteOption=0

        pSites[0].cServers=1

    NC:     pNCs[0].pszName=ForestDnsZones
        pNCs[0].pszDn=DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=mcad,DC=local

            pNCs[0].aCrInfo[0].dwFlags=0x00000201
            pNCs[0].aCrInfo[0].pszDn=CN=053f2400-35fe-4529-a535-d8d649587484,CN=Partitions,CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local
            pNCs[0].aCrInfo[0].pszDnsRoot=ForestDnsZones.mcad.local
            pNCs[0].aCrInfo[0].iSourceServer=0
            pNCs[0].aCrInfo[0].pszSourceServer=(null)
            pNCs[0].aCrInfo[0].ulSystemFlags=0x00000005
            pNCs[0].aCrInfo[0].bEnabled=TRUE
            pNCs[0].aCrInfo[0].ftWhenCreated=00000000 00000000          pNCs[0].aCrInfo[0].pszSDReferenceDomain=(null)
            pNCs[0].aCrInfo[0].pszNetBiosName=(null)
            pNCs[0].aCrInfo[0].cReplicas=-1
            pNCs[0].aCrInfo[0].aszReplicas=


    NC:     pNCs[1].pszName=DomainDnsZones
        pNCs[1].pszDn=DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=mcad,DC=local

            pNCs[1].aCrInfo[0].dwFlags=0x00000201
            pNCs[1].aCrInfo[0].pszDn=CN=fc0257f3-c228-4082-8647-08354ec0dd25,CN=Partitions,CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local
            pNCs[1].aCrInfo[0].pszDnsRoot=DomainDnsZones.mcad.local
            pNCs[1].aCrInfo[0].iSourceServer=0
            pNCs[1].aCrInfo[0].pszSourceServer=(null)
            pNCs[1].aCrInfo[0].ulSystemFlags=0x00000005
            pNCs[1].aCrInfo[0].bEnabled=TRUE
            pNCs[1].aCrInfo[0].ftWhenCreated=00000000 00000000          pNCs[1].aCrInfo[0].pszSDReferenceDomain=(null)
            pNCs[1].aCrInfo[0].pszNetBiosName=(null)
            pNCs[1].aCrInfo[0].cReplicas=-1
            pNCs[1].aCrInfo[0].aszReplicas=


    NC:     pNCs[2].pszName=Schema
        pNCs[2].pszDn=CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local

            pNCs[2].aCrInfo[0].dwFlags=0x00000201
            pNCs[2].aCrInfo[0].pszDn=CN=Enterprise Schema,CN=Partitions,CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local
            pNCs[2].aCrInfo[0].pszDnsRoot=mcad.local
            pNCs[2].aCrInfo[0].iSourceServer=0
            pNCs[2].aCrInfo[0].pszSourceServer=(null)
            pNCs[2].aCrInfo[0].ulSystemFlags=0x00000001
            pNCs[2].aCrInfo[0].bEnabled=TRUE
            pNCs[2].aCrInfo[0].ftWhenCreated=00000000 00000000          pNCs[2].aCrInfo[0].pszSDReferenceDomain=(null)
            pNCs[2].aCrInfo[0].pszNetBiosName=(null)
            pNCs[2].aCrInfo[0].cReplicas=-1
            pNCs[2].aCrInfo[0].aszReplicas=


    NC:     pNCs[3].pszName=Configuration
        pNCs[3].pszDn=CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local

            pNCs[3].aCrInfo[0].dwFlags=0x00000201
            pNCs[3].aCrInfo[0].pszDn=CN=Enterprise Configuration,CN=Partitions,CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local
            pNCs[3].aCrInfo[0].pszDnsRoot=mcad.local
            pNCs[3].aCrInfo[0].iSourceServer=0
            pNCs[3].aCrInfo[0].pszSourceServer=(null)
            pNCs[3].aCrInfo[0].ulSystemFlags=0x00000001
            pNCs[3].aCrInfo[0].bEnabled=TRUE
            pNCs[3].aCrInfo[0].ftWhenCreated=00000000 00000000          pNCs[3].aCrInfo[0].pszSDReferenceDomain=(null)
            pNCs[3].aCrInfo[0].pszNetBiosName=(null)
            pNCs[3].aCrInfo[0].cReplicas=-1
            pNCs[3].aCrInfo[0].aszReplicas=


    NC:     pNCs[4].pszName=mcad
        pNCs[4].pszDn=DC=mcad,DC=local

            pNCs[4].aCrInfo[0].dwFlags=0x00000201
            pNCs[4].aCrInfo[0].pszDn=CN=MCAD,CN=Partitions,CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local
            pNCs[4].aCrInfo[0].pszDnsRoot=mcad.local
            pNCs[4].aCrInfo[0].iSourceServer=0
            pNCs[4].aCrInfo[0].pszSourceServer=(null)
            pNCs[4].aCrInfo[0].ulSystemFlags=0x00000003
            pNCs[4].aCrInfo[0].bEnabled=TRUE
            pNCs[4].aCrInfo[0].ftWhenCreated=00000000 00000000          pNCs[4].aCrInfo[0].pszSDReferenceDomain=(null)
            pNCs[4].aCrInfo[0].pszNetBiosName=(null)
            pNCs[4].aCrInfo[0].cReplicas=-1
            pNCs[4].aCrInfo[0].aszReplicas=


    5 NC TARGETS: ForestDnsZones, DomainDnsZones, Schema, Configuration, mcad, 
    1 TARGETS: SERVER, 

=============================================Done Printing pDsInfo

Doing initial required tests
   
   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\SERVER
      Starting test: Connectivity
         * Active Directory LDAP Services Check
         Failure Analysis: SERVER ... OK.
         * Active Directory RPC Services Check
         ......................... SERVER passed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests
   
   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\SERVER
      Starting test: Replications
         * Replications Check
         DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=mcad,DC=local has 10 cursors.
         DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=mcad,DC=local has 9 cursors.
         CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local has 10 cursors.
         CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local has 10 cursors.
         DC=mcad,DC=local has 9 cursors.
         * Replication Latency Check
            DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=mcad,DC=local
               Latency information for 9 entries in the vector were ignored.
                  9 were retired Invocations.  0 were either: read-only replicas and are not verifiably latent, or dc's no longer replicating this nc.  0 had no latency information (Win2K DC).  
            DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=mcad,DC=local
               Latency information for 8 entries in the vector were ignored.
                  8 were retired Invocations.  0 were either: read-only replicas and are not verifiably latent, or dc's no longer replicating this nc.  0 had no latency information (Win2K DC).  
            CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local
               Latency information for 9 entries in the vector were ignored.
                  9 were retired Invocations.  0 were either: read-only replicas and are not verifiably latent, or dc's no longer replicating this nc.  0 had no latency information (Win2K DC).  
            CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local
               Latency information for 9 entries in the vector were ignored.
                  9 were retired Invocations.  0 were either: read-only replicas and are not verifiably latent, or dc's no longer replicating this nc.  0 had no latency information (Win2K DC).  
            DC=mcad,DC=local
               Latency information for 8 entries in the vector were ignored.
                  8 were retired Invocations.  0 were either: read-only replicas and are not verifiably latent, or dc's no longer replicating this nc.  0 had no latency information (Win2K DC).  
         ......................... SERVER passed test Replications
      Starting test: Topology
         * Configuration Topology Integrity Check
         * Analyzing the connection topology for DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=mcad,DC=local.
         * Performing upstream (of target) analysis.
         * Performing downstream (of target) analysis.
         * Analyzing the connection topology for DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=mcad,DC=local.
         * Performing upstream (of target) analysis.
         * Performing downstream (of target) analysis.
         * Analyzing the connection topology for CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local.
         * Performing upstream (of target) analysis.
         * Performing downstream (of target) analysis.
         * Analyzing the connection topology for CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local.
         * Performing upstream (of target) analysis.
         * Performing downstream (of target) analysis.
         * Analyzing the connection topology for DC=mcad,DC=local.
         * Performing upstream (of target) analysis.
         * Performing downstream (of target) analysis.
         ......................... SERVER passed test Topology
      Starting test: CutoffServers
         * Configuration Topology Aliveness Check
         * Analyzing the alive system replication topology for DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=mcad,DC=local.
         * Performing upstream (of target) analysis.
         * Performing downstream (of target) analysis.
         * Analyzing the alive system replication topology for DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=mcad,DC=local.
         * Performing upstream (of target) analysis.
         * Performing downstream (of target) analysis.
         * Analyzing the alive system replication topology for CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local.
         * Performing upstream (of target) analysis.
         * Performing downstream (of target) analysis.
         * Analyzing the alive system replication topology for CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local.
         * Performing upstream (of target) analysis.
         * Performing downstream (of target) analysis.
         * Analyzing the alive system replication topology for DC=mcad,DC=local.
         * Performing upstream (of target) analysis.
         * Performing downstream (of target) analysis.
         ......................... SERVER passed test CutoffServers
      Starting test: NCSecDesc
         * Security Permissions check for all NC's on DC SERVER.
         * Security Permissions Check for
           DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=mcad,DC=local
            (NDNC,Version 2)
         * Security Permissions Check for
           DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=mcad,DC=local
            (NDNC,Version 2)
         * Security Permissions Check for
           CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local
            (Schema,Version 2)
         * Security Permissions Check for
           CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local
            (Configuration,Version 2)
         * Security Permissions Check for
           DC=mcad,DC=local
            (Domain,Version 2)
         ......................... SERVER passed test NCSecDesc
      Starting test: NetLogons
         * Network Logons Privileges Check
         Verified share \\SERVER\netlogon
         Verified share \\SERVER\sysvol
         ......................... SERVER passed test NetLogons
      Starting test: Advertising
         The DC SERVER is advertising itself as a DC and having a DS.
         The DC SERVER is advertising as an LDAP server
         The DC SERVER is advertising as having a writeable directory
         The DC SERVER is advertising as a Key Distribution Center
         The DC SERVER is advertising as a time server
         The DS SERVER is advertising as a GC.
         ......................... SERVER passed test Advertising
      Starting test: KnowsOfRoleHolders
         Role Schema Owner = CN=NTDS Settings,CN=SERVER,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local
         Role Domain Owner = CN=NTDS Settings,CN=SERVER,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local
         Role PDC Owner = CN=NTDS Settings,CN=SERVER,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local
         Role Rid Owner = CN=NTDS Settings,CN=SERVER,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local
         Role Infrastructure Update Owner = CN=NTDS Settings,CN=SERVER,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local
         ......................... SERVER passed test KnowsOfRoleHolders
      Starting test: RidManager
         ridManagerReference = CN=RID Manager$,CN=System,DC=mcad,DC=local
         * Available RID Pool for the Domain is 8109 to 1073741823
         fSMORoleOwner = CN=NTDS Settings,CN=SERVER,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local
         * SERVER.mcad.local is the RID Master
         * DsBind with RID Master was successful
         rIDSetReferences = CN=RID Set,CN=SERVER,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=mcad,DC=local
         * rIDAllocationPool is 7609 to 8108
         * rIDPreviousAllocationPool is 5109 to 5608
         * rIDNextRID: 5461
         ......................... SERVER passed test RidManager
      Starting test: MachineAccount
         Checking machine account for DC SERVER on DC SERVER.
         * SPN found :LDAP/SERVER.mcad.local/mcad.local
         * SPN found :LDAP/SERVER.mcad.local
         * SPN found :LDAP/SERVER
         * SPN found :LDAP/SERVER.mcad.local/MCAD
         * SPN found :LDAP/12a36ed6-9156-4bb8-9d8a-f523bd78ff47._msdcs.mcad.local
         * SPN found :E3514235-4B06-11D1-AB04-00C04FC2DCD2/12a36ed6-9156-4bb8-9d8a-f523bd78ff47/mcad.local
         * SPN found :HOST/SERVER.mcad.local/mcad.local
         * SPN found :HOST/SERVER.mcad.local
         * SPN found :HOST/SERVER
         * SPN found :HOST/SERVER.mcad.local/MCAD
         * SPN found :GC/SERVER.mcad.local/mcad.local
         ......................... SERVER passed test MachineAccount
      Starting test: Services
         * Checking Service: Dnscache
         * Checking Service: NtFrs
         * Checking Service: IsmServ
         * Checking Service: kdc
         * Checking Service: SamSs
         * Checking Service: LanmanServer
         * Checking Service: LanmanWorkstation
         * Checking Service: RpcSs
         * Checking Service: w32time
         * Checking Service: NETLOGON
         ......................... SERVER passed test Services
      Starting test: OutboundSecureChannels
         * The Outbound Secure Channels test
         ** Did not run Outbound Secure Channels test
         because /testdomain: was not entered
         ......................... SERVER passed test OutboundSecureChannels
      Starting test: ObjectsReplicated
         SERVER is in domain DC=mcad,DC=local
         Checking for CN=SERVER,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=mcad,DC=local in domain DC=mcad,DC=local on 1 servers
            Object is up-to-date on all servers.
         Checking for CN=NTDS Settings,CN=SERVER,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local in domain CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local on 1 servers
            Object is up-to-date on all servers.
         ......................... SERVER passed test ObjectsReplicated
      Starting test: frssysvol
         * The File Replication Service SYSVOL ready test 
         File Replication Service's SYSVOL is ready 
         ......................... SERVER passed test frssysvol
      Starting test: frsevent
         * The File Replication Service Event log test 
         ......................... SERVER passed test frsevent
      Starting test: kccevent
         * The KCC Event log test
         Found no KCC errors in Directory Service Event log in the last 15 minutes.
         ......................... SERVER passed test kccevent
      Starting test: systemlog
         * The System Event log test
         Found no errors in System Event log in the last 60 minutes.
         ......................... SERVER passed test systemlog
      Starting test: VerifyReplicas
         ......................... SERVER passed test VerifyReplicas
      Starting test: VerifyReferences
         The system object reference (serverReference)

         CN=SERVER,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=mcad,DC=local and backlink on

         CN=SERVER,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local

         are correct. 
         The system object reference (frsComputerReferenceBL)

         CN=SERVER,CN=Domain System Volume (SYSVOL share),CN=File Replication Service,CN=System,DC=mcad,DC=local

         and backlink on CN=SERVER,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=mcad,DC=local are

         correct. 
         The system object reference (serverReferenceBL)

         CN=SERVER,CN=Domain System Volume (SYSVOL share),CN=File Replication Service,CN=System,DC=mcad,DC=local

         and backlink on

         CN=NTDS Settings,CN=SERVER,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local

         are correct. 
         ......................... SERVER passed test VerifyReferences
      Starting test: VerifyEnterpriseReferences
         ......................... SERVER passed test VerifyEnterpriseReferences
      Starting test: CheckSecurityError
         * Dr Auth:  Beginning security errors check!
         Found KDC SERVER for domain mcad.local in site Default-First-Site-Name
         Checking machine account for DC SERVER on DC SERVER.
         * SPN found :LDAP/SERVER.mcad.local/mcad.local
         * SPN found :LDAP/SERVER.mcad.local
         * SPN found :LDAP/SERVER
         * SPN found :LDAP/SERVER.mcad.local/MCAD
         * SPN found :LDAP/12a36ed6-9156-4bb8-9d8a-f523bd78ff47._msdcs.mcad.local
         * SPN found :E3514235-4B06-11D1-AB04-00C04FC2DCD2/12a36ed6-9156-4bb8-9d8a-f523bd78ff47/mcad.local
         * SPN found :HOST/SERVER.mcad.local/mcad.local
         * SPN found :HOST/SERVER.mcad.local
         * SPN found :HOST/SERVER
         * SPN found :HOST/SERVER.mcad.local/MCAD
         * SPN found :GC/SERVER.mcad.local/mcad.local
         [SERVER] No security related replication errors were found on this DC!  To target the connection to a specific source DC use /ReplSource:<DC>.
         ......................... SERVER passed test CheckSecurityError

DNS Tests are running and not hung. Please wait a few minutes...
   
   Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CrossRefValidation
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
   
   Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CrossRefValidation
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom
   
   Running partition tests on : Schema
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Schema passed test CrossRefValidation
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Schema passed test CheckSDRefDom
   
   Running partition tests on : Configuration
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Configuration passed test CrossRefValidation
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Configuration passed test CheckSDRefDom
   
   Running partition tests on : mcad
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... mcad passed test CrossRefValidation
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... mcad passed test CheckSDRefDom
   
   Running enterprise tests on : mcad.local
      Starting test: Intersite
         Skipping site Default-First-Site-Name, this site is outside the scope

         provided by the command line arguments provided. 
         ......................... mcad.local passed test Intersite
      Starting test: FsmoCheck
         GC Name: \\SERVER.mcad.local
         Locator Flags: 0xe00001fd
         PDC Name: \\SERVER.mcad.local
         Locator Flags: 0xe00001fd
         Time Server Name: \\SERVER.mcad.local
         Locator Flags: 0xe00001fd
         Preferred Time Server Name: \\SERVER.mcad.local
         Locator Flags: 0xe00001fd
         KDC Name: \\SERVER.mcad.local
         Locator Flags: 0xe00001fd
         ......................... mcad.local passed test FsmoCheck
      Starting test: DNS
         Test results for domain controllers:
            
            DC: SERVER.mcad.local
            Domain: mcad.local

                  
               TEST: Authentication (Auth)
                  Authentication test: Successfully completed
                  
               TEST: Basic (Basc)
                   Microsoft(R) Windows(R) Server 2003 for Small Business Server (Service Pack level: 2.0) is supported
                  NETLOGON service is running
                  kdc service is running
                  DNSCACHE service is running
                  DNS service is running
                  DC is a DNS server
                  Network adapters information:
                  Adapter [00000010] Realtek RTL8139/810x Family Fast Ethernet NIC:
                     MAC address is 00:0E:0C:3E:56:EB
                     IP address is static
                     IP address: 192.168.1.1
                     DNS servers:
                        127.0.0.1 (server.mcad.local.) [Valid]
                  The A record for this DC was found
                  The SOA record for the Active Directory zone was found
                  The Active Directory zone on this DC/DNS server was found (primary)
                  Root zone on this DC/DNS server was not found
                  
               TEST: Forwarders/Root hints (Forw)
                  Recursion is enabled
                  Forwarders Information: 
                     195.162.32.5 (<name unavailable>) [Valid] 
                     217.25.208.6 (<name unavailable>) [Valid] 
                     217.25.209.2 (<name unavailable>) [Valid] 
                     77.88.8.1 (<name unavailable>) [Valid] 
                     77.88.8.8 (<name unavailable>) [Valid] 
                     8.8.8.8 (<name unavailable>) [Valid] 
                  
               TEST: Delegations (Del)
                  Delegation information for the zone: mcad.local.
                     Delegated domain name: _msdcs.mcad.local.
                        DNS server: server.mcad.local. IP:192.168.1.1 [Valid] 
                  
               TEST: Dynamic update (Dyn)
                  Dynamic update is enabled on the zone mcad.local.
                  Test record _dcdiag_test_record added successfully in zone mcad.local.
                  Test record _dcdiag_test_record deleted successfully in zone mcad.local.
                  
               TEST: Records registration (RReg)
                  Network Adapter [00000010] Realtek RTL8139/810x Family Fast Ethernet NIC:
                     Matching A record found at DNS server 192.168.1.1:
                     SERVER.mcad.local

                     Matching CNAME record found at DNS server 192.168.1.1:
                     12a36ed6-9156-4bb8-9d8a-f523bd78ff47._msdcs.mcad.local

                     Matching DC SRV record found at DNS server 192.168.1.1:
                     _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.mcad.local

                     Matching GC SRV record found at DNS server 192.168.1.1:
                     _ldap._tcp.gc._msdcs.mcad.local

                     Matching PDC SRV record found at DNS server 192.168.1.1:
                     _ldap._tcp.pdc._msdcs.mcad.local

               Total query time:0 min. 0 sec.. Total RPC connection time:0 min. 0 sec.
               Total WMI connection time:4 min. 11 sec. Total Netuse connection time:0 min. 0 sec.
         
         Summary of test results for DNS servers used by the above domain controllers:

            DNS server: 192.168.1.1 (server.mcad.local.)
               All tests passed on this DNS server
               This is a valid DNS server 
               Name resolution is funtional. _ldap._tcp SRV record for the forest root domain is registered 
               Delegation to the domain _msdcs.mcad.local. is operational
               Total query time:0 min. 0 sec., Total WMI connection time:0 min. 0 sec.
               
            DNS server: 195.162.32.5 (<name unavailable>)
               All tests passed on this DNS server
               This is a valid DNS server 
               Total query time:0 min. 0 sec., Total WMI connection time:0 min. 41 sec.
               
            DNS server: 217.25.208.6 (<name unavailable>)
               All tests passed on this DNS server
               This is a valid DNS server 
               Total query time:0 min. 0 sec., Total WMI connection time:0 min. 42 sec.
               
            DNS server: 217.25.209.2 (<name unavailable>)
               All tests passed on this DNS server
               This is a valid DNS server 
               Total query time:0 min. 0 sec., Total WMI connection time:0 min. 42 sec.
               
            DNS server: 77.88.8.1 (<name unavailable>)
               All tests passed on this DNS server
               This is a valid DNS server 
               Total query time:0 min. 0 sec., Total WMI connection time:0 min. 41 sec.
               
            DNS server: 77.88.8.8 (<name unavailable>)
               All tests passed on this DNS server
               This is a valid DNS server 
               Total query time:0 min. 0 sec., Total WMI connection time:0 min. 41 sec.
               
            DNS server: 8.8.8.8 (<name unavailable>)
               All tests passed on this DNS server
               This is a valid DNS server 
               Total query time:0 min. 0 sec., Total WMI connection time:0 min. 41 sec.
               
         Summary of DNS test results:
         
                                            Auth Basc Forw Del  Dyn  RReg Ext  
               ________________________________________________________________
            Domain: mcad.local
               SERVER                       PASS PASS PASS PASS PASS PASS n/a  
         
         Total Time taken to test all the DCs:4 min. 12 sec.
         ......................... mcad.local passed test DNS
```

except the part with replication testing:

```
      Starting test: Replications
         * Replications Check
         DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=mcad,DC=local has 10 cursors.
         DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=mcad,DC=local has 9 cursors.
         CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local has 10 cursors.
         CN=Configuration,DC=mcad,DC=local has 10 cursors.
         DC=mcad,DC=local has 9 cursors.
         * Replication Latency Check
            DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=mcad,DC=local
               Latency information for 9 entries in the vector were ignored.
                  9 were retired Invocations.  0 were either: read-only replicas and are not verifiably latent, or dc's no longer replicating this nc.  0 had no latency information (Win2K DC).  
         ......................... SERVER passed test Replications
```

but I don't know how to interpret these results and if these are errors at all. Any help would be welcome!

Comment: Try to move to 2019 if possible. EoL for 2016 is 2022, but extended is 2027. Biggest reason to move to 2019 is that updates on 2016 take much longer to install compared to 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you cannot directly upgrade from Server 2003 to Server 2016. I managed to upgrade to Server 2008 R2 at first. Then I did FRS to DFS migration (you cannot upgrade to Server 2016 without this step) and raise domain and forest levels. And finally I upgraded to Server 2016.

Answer (score 1):

While it would be possible to migrate directly from 2003 to 2016 (but not 2019, as it [requires](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/active-directory-functional-levels) Windows Server 2008 functional level), I recall *Small Business Server* (SBS) being quite a different beast, having some adjustments that may cause some unnecessary burden. With SBS licensing you were only allowed to have one Windows Server in your environment, which is against all other recommendations of having at least two domain controllers, and that might also be a cause why your migration is not going as expected.

Your current environment and approach have at least three challenges:

1. Moving from 2003 to 2016 is quite a leap.
2. Moving out from SBS.
3. You are using a `.local` domain, which is [not recommended](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34981.active-directory-best-practices-for-internal-domain-and-network-names.aspx#Dummy_DNS_name_vs_official_DNS_name).

Unless it's absolutely impossible to create a new Windows AD from scratch and migrate the data rather than the current AD domain, I would suggest installing a fresh AD with a publicly registered `ad.example.com` subdomain. As SBS was designed for small companies with 25 to 50 workstations, it shouldn't be an out of question task in a small environment like that.

Comment: +1 for setting up a new domain with a valid name. You'll save yourself a lot of headaches in the long run!

Comment: It is unlikely scenario to deploy a new domain from scratch. Microsoft's sbs team says it is absolutely possible to have another DC in a domain with SBS server acting as PDC: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-server-essentials-and/debunking-myths-about-additional-domain-controllers-in-sbs/ba-p/395878. Furthermore there's a couple of questions on the internet that approve migration is possible: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0284a1be-67a2-4769-80b0-c4073d0f05c6/transferring-fsmo-roles-from-2003-sbs-to-2012-r2?forum=winserverMigration

Answer (score 0):

Most likely caused by RPC ports being closed on the replication target. Make sure the ports are opened / not filtered.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Firewalls are turned off on both servers. I can successfully connect to tcp port 135 from one server to another. So it's not the case.